# Implementation of Union find Algorithm

Tags: c++

I have a series of Key value pairs. Each Key has 2 values. Values of Keys may coincide.
Initially, I start with Key1, ValueKey1, ValueKey2 are stored in a set (maybe array).

Now for each consecutive Keyi, I check if Valuei and Valuei+1 are in the set. If any one of them is in the set, then join the set.

Else if both KeyValues are present in a set, discard that key.

How can I implement this thing using C++, I have very little idea, so if possible a code snippet or a hint would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't understand your setup. First you say you have "key-value pairs", and then you say that "each key has two values". What's the basic unit of data that you have? Could you please clarify?

Comment: i have suppose an int value, for that int i have two associated values int a, int b. Now i have many such pairs and have to use union find algorithm to see if any of the key-value pairs coincide...

Comment: Does this have to do with graphs?

Comment: @AusCBloke well the thing is i am generating a maze. To remove walls i have numbered the rooms corresponding to it. And yes later they are implemented as graphs !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using or in possession of **'Algorithms in C++**' (Sedgewick, 3rd ed.) by any chance?

The first problem that is encountered in the book is that of connectivity (page 7) , and in it there are multiple implementations of a union-find (quick-union, quick-find, weighted etc) algorithm that uses paired keys.

Here's the quick-find version: (This is just  a re-type from the book - not tested)

```
#include <iostream>
const int N = 10000;
int main() {
    int i, p, q, id[N];
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) id[i] = i;
    while( cin >> p >> q ) {
        int t = id[p];
        if ( t = id[q] ) continue;
        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            if ( id[i] == t) id[i] = id[q];
        cout << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
}
```

Just keeps spitting out pairs that aren't connected (which you could probably invert to get what you want)

The book has a pretty detailed description of how it works - and I'm guessing that you have it for now.

Comment: No Sir.. I do not have that book. Let me try your solution. Thanks.